# PHP Request time out on simple function

Tags: php, codeigniter, request, timeout

I have this function which calculates 'Book Value' of fixed assets using data from the depreciation table, Ii is working fine on localhost but when I tried to go on production, am getting 'request time out' after taking long time to load, I think I messed up with looping or something and It will be great if anyone suggest code optimization or hack to make this function  faster.

I tried to limit the number of records to loop and It worked but unfortunately, I have over 20,000 data to process.

```
    $cat = null;
    $total_a = null;
    $assets = $this->Depreciation->get_all();

    if (!empty($assets)) {
        foreach ($assets as $asset) {

            $cost = $asset->cost + $asset->add_cost + $asset->adj_cost;
            $salve = $asset->salvage_value;
            $life = $asset->life;
            $life_t = 0;
            $counter = 0;
            $date1 = date('Y-12-31');
            $date2 = $asset->in_service;

            $diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

            $years = floor($diff / (365 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (30 * 60 * 60 * 24));

            $in_service_d = date('Y-12-31');


            if ($asset->rev > 0) {
                $cost = $asset->rev;
            }


            $dep1 = ($cost - $salve) / $life * ($months / 12);
            $dep = ($cost - $salve) / $life;


            $total = 0;
            $year = 1;


            for (; $cost > $salve;) {
                if ($year == 1 && $months < 12) {
                    $life_t++;
                    $year++;
                    $cost = $cost - $dep1;
                    $counter++;
                    $total = $dep1 + $total;

                    if($in_service_d == date('Y-12-31')){
                        $total_a = $total_a + $cost;
                    }

                    $in_service_d = date('Y-12-31', strtotime("+12 months", strtotime($in_service_d)));


                } elseif ($year != 1) {
                    $life_t++;
                    if ($life_t > $life) {
                        $dep = $dep - $dep1;
                    }
                    $cost = $cost - $dep;
                    $counter++;
                    $total = $dep + $total;

                    if($in_service_d == date('Y-12-31')){
                        $total_a = $total_a + $cost;
                    }

                    $in_service_d = date('Y-12-31', strtotime("+12 months", strtotime($in_service_d)));

                }

            }

        }

    }

     return $total_a;
```

Comment: If there is no database operations involved, 20,000 row is not a particularly huge set of data. I haven't go through the whole program logic yet, but you loop runs as long as `$cost` is larger than `$salve`. Are you sure that either the `$cost` is coming down, or `$salve` is going up through out the iterations?

Comment: One advice: your program logics are too complicated to be tested. I'd recommend you to breakdown your logics into smaller functions and have each of them tested. That way you'd have more certainty to what each part is doing.

Comment: Cost is coming down `$cost = $cost - $dep1; `  or  `$cost = $cost - $dep;` depend on ` $Year` on each iteration

Comment: Am suspecting the problem is with loop, but I can't figure out how this loop take so long for just 21 records.

Comment: Can we have some example data of `$asset`? It is hard to make sense of your program logic.

Comment: Also, it helps if you `var_dump` some of the key variables within your loop. That usually helps you tracking down what causes the problem. I bet `$cost` is not coming down the way you expected.

Comment: You mean like this : https://unsee.cc/ffb26821/

Comment: I tried one of your data and run it 20,000 times. And it finishes in 8 seconds. So I don't think this is a crazy long computation.  I think there is probably one particular row that caused the issue. I'd suggest you to put a `var_dump($asset->a_id);` at the beginning of your `foreach` loop. Then run and see which asset got you stucked.

Comment: Found one logical problem. The for-loop would go on forever if `$months` is bigger than 12. Not sure if it is actually happening, thou.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is the `set_time_limit()` function.

I had a similar script of exporting a formatted Excel file from a large database. The script would always run out of time whenever it exceeded over 1,000 rows.

In the `loop` section of my logic, I set up the following:

```
set_time_limit(30);
```

Which would extend the allowed time to run for another 30 seconds from that point onward.

Comment: Mine run out of time with just 21 records, When you add that function what about user experience? I think user will have to wait for some time for operation to complete and unfortunately this function run just after login in my app

Comment: My requirement was for a download script, so there was a fair warning from the user that they'll have to wait a bit.  Are you sure your script runs out after 21 records?  But it runs smoothly on localhost?  What's the script timeout on the server?  And, what's the size of the full dataset that needs to be processed?  Could it be a memory size issue?